# C# - Creating instances of objects found in dll's during the runtime

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my code and can't figure it out where is the problem.

Aim is to search some dll's which implements interface and after that, create instances of them.

This is what I did by now:

```
List<ISomeInterface> instances = new List<ISomeInterface>();

String startFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "FolderWithDLLS");

foreach (var f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
         var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(f);
         var types = assembly.GetTypes();

         foreach (var type in types)
         {
             if (type.GetInterface("ISomeInterface") != null)
             {
                  //line bellow shows errors about some invalid arguments
                  //default constructor doesn't need any parameters.
                  instances.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(type));
             }
         }
         assembly = null;
}
```

Error: `the best overloaded match for method System.Collections.Generic.List<ISomeInterface>.Add(ISomeInterface) has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Could you post the full error you are getting?

Comment: catch (Exception e) { //who cares?}  YOU. You DO care.

Comment: ` catch (Exception e) { //who cares?  }` **I do ...** ... if you don't care about your exceptions, how can you seriously ask others to care?

Comment: Why you don't use just simply the type's AssemblyQualifiedname and then simply call it with Activator.CreateInstance() ?

Comment: Guys i putted it just for fun here(problem is not about it), why so much hate?
I dont even compile this code, visual shows error which i posted.

Comment: @GrantWinney wtf I don't get your position here, question it's not even about that exception which is NOT RELEVANT here.

Comment: @GrantWinney Ok maybe that wasn't cool - I had to think what do with exxception later, after solving casting issues o i just putted something during pasting, that's all. In the other hand, I think You overreacted like the rest of the people. I dont care about votes but You needen't throw meat on me.
I see You guys are pretty serious here.

Comment: Actually my question is pretty bad - missed object cast -.-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Activator.CreateInstance(type)` returns an `object`.

`instances.Add()` wants an `ISomeInterface`.

So you need to cast it.

```
instances.Add((ISomeInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
```

Comment: I dont know how did I miss it. It's kinda late in my country. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

You have a strongly typed list but `CreateInstance` method returns object so you need to cast it

```
instances.Add((ISomeInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
```